# Controller path not found in MVC project using Knockout JS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC web application that I am working on and one of the pages uses a javascript file for the data.

```
I have the TournamentInfo.js file in a folder called "Scripts"
I have the TournamentController.cs file in a folder called "Controllers"
I have the TourneyInfo.cshtml file in a folder called "Tourneys" that is in a folder called "Views"
```

When I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
[Htpp Exception] The controller for path &#39;/Tourneys/TourneyInfo&#39; was not found or does not implement IController
```

I have another page in my project that is set up using the same format (javascript file, controller file, and view file) and that page works without a problem. I can't find a difference that would be causing the error that I am receiving.

Any suggestions on what I should be looking for to fix the problem on my tournaments page?

*If you would like to see the code for each of the files, let me know. I wasn't sure if it would be relevant or not since my other page using this format works.

Javscript file:

```
function tournamentpageModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Tournaments = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function TourneyInfo(_name, _date, _location, _pattern, _avg, _finish, _ttlentries) {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable(_name);
    self.Date = ko.observable(_date);
    self.Loc = ko.observable(_location);
    self.Pattern = ko.observable(_pattern);
    self.Avg = ko.observable(_avg);
    self.Finish = ko.observable(_finish);
    self.Entries = ko.observable(_ttlentries);
}

var viewTModel = new tournamentpageModel();
viewTModel.Tournaments.push(new TourneyInfo("South Regional", "May 9-10, 2014", "Rocky Mount, NC", "Chameleon (41ft)", "167.75", "70th", "75"));
viewTModel.Tournaments.push(new TourneyInfo("South Regional", "March 7-9, 2014", "Pensacola, FL", "Badger (52ft)", "215.75", "17th", ""));
viewTModel.Tournaments.push(new TourneyInfo("South Regional", "", "Pensacola, FL", "", "", "", ""));
viewTModel.Tournaments.push(new TourneyInfo("South Regional", "", "Canton, GA", "Viper (39ft)", "215.75", "14th", ""));


$(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(viewTModel);
})
```

Controller:

```
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PracticeApp.Controllers
{
    public class TournamentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult TourneyInfo()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Models/TournamentInfo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tournaments";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</hgroup>

<table id="sponsorTable">
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: TourneyInfo">
        <tr>
            <th>Tournament Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Location</th><th>Oil Pattern</th><th>Quailfying Avg</th><th>Finished</th><th>Total Entries</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Date"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Loc"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Pattern"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Avg"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Finish"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Entries"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Shared layout....contains the actionlinks for the nav menu. They all work except the tournaments link. They all use the same format in the overloads ("Hyperlink Text", "File Name", "Folder Name"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Atlas Web Pages</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="web-header">
                <div class="logo-image">
                    <img src="~/Images/Atlas.png" style="float: left" height="125" width="150" alt="Atlas Logo" />
                    <img style="vertical-align:top" src="~/Images/WebPageLogo.png" height="85" width="820" alt="Atlas Logo" />
                    <div style="color:#FFF">*A southpaw's approach to bowling*</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="float-right">
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("The Team", "About", "About")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Current Line-Up", "CurrentList", "Current")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Retired Equipment", "RetiredList", "Retired")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tournaments", "TourneyInfo", "Tourneys")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bowling Videos", "Videos", "Video")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sponsors", "Sponsors", "Sponsor")</li>   
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year: Southpaw Web Solutions&trade; - Email: jmilam90@gmail.com</p>
                        <p>Stylized drawing of the god, Atlas, courtesy of shutterstock</p>

                    </div>
                    <div id="follow-icons">
                            <a href ="www.facebook.com/jmilam90"><img src="~/Images/FBIcon.png" alt="Follow on Facebook" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                            <a href ="www.twitter.com/jmilam900"><img src="~/Images/TwitIcon.png" alt="Follow on twitter" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <table id="logo-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/MBW.png" width="99" height="60" alt="McCorveys Bowling World Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/EboniteLogo.png" width="93" height="60" alt="Ebonite Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/TrackLogo.png" width="152" height="60" alt="Track Bowling Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/HammerLogo.png" width="100" height="60" alt="Hammer Bowling Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/ColumbiaLogo.png" width="123" height="60" alt="Columbia 300 Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/PBALogo.png" width="60" height="60" alt="PBA Logo" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </footer>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The path for the TourneyInfo view should be something like /Tournament instead.  I,e you are referencing your View and not the controller.  MVC routing will not be able to reconcile this request.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call the TourneyInfo action on the Tourneys controller(should be Tournament controller?).  It would be helpful to see the Controller and the code that calls the controller.

Comment: I'll post the code for the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention is for paths to use the prefix of the controller name, so you should navigate to:

```
/Tournament/TourneyInfo/
```

Instead of:

```
/Tourneys/TourneyInfo/
```

You may find Glimpse useful to determine which routes were tried before the failure was reported:

http://getglimpse.com/

**Edit**: also see the comments below. Another issue was the location of the view - by default, views need to be in the `Views\<ControllerName>\` folder, e.g. `Views\Tournament\`.

Comment: These are my action links. They all work except the Tournaments one.
`<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("The Team", "About", "About")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Current Line-Up", "CurrentList", "Current")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Retired Equipment", "RetiredList", "Retired")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Tournaments", "TourneyInfo", "Tourneys")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Bowling Videos", "Videos", "Video")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Sponsors", "Sponsors", "Sponsor")</li>`

Comment: Changing the navigation to the controller didn't fix the problem either. I ran out of characters in the last comment, but each link checks for the folder that equals the 3rd string listed, then the file name that matches the 2nd string listed. The first string is the text that displays in the nav menu on the page

Comment: Your controller is called 'TournamentController', not 'TourneysController', so the ActionLink should reflect that: @Html.ActionLink("Tournaments", "TourneyInfo", "Tournament")

Comment: All of my action links look for the Folder name that the file is located in and then the File name that is in that folder. They all work except for the tournaments link. I did try you suggestion of looking for "Tournament" and even "TournamentController" just to make sure, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is your 'TourneyInfo' view located in a 'Tournament' folder underneath 'Views'? By default, view folders should correspond with controller names, too - i.e. if it's in a 'Tourneys' folder, it will fail. These rules are part of the convention-based routing system which MVC uses by default. There's more about them here (plus the following page, too): http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-controller

Comment: Ah i see. That was my problem. Thank you for that explanation!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted :)